# Create com class wrapper in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way I can create a com class wrapper when developing in VS 2010?
If so  how do I add a reference to the COM type library?

Comment: do you know how to add a reference to a normal assembly / Dll Lib..?
please make your question more specific..what is it that you want to do with vs2010 IDE...?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a generic marshalling wrapper (e.g. no logic, just marshalling types)  here are 2 ways:

1. Right click on your project, click "Add Reference", choose the "COM" section on the far left, and search for the library you want to import.
2. Use [TLBIMP.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create a wrapper class and add that to your project.

Comment: For a 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException', what kind of library should be added as a reference?

Comment: That's a .NET type in the core library, not a COM library.  What are you trying to do? (don't answer here, add to your question)